# Linker Error with Boost.Log

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I am trying to use boost logger  when I compile and link the program as shown below, I get the following error. My OS is macOSHighSierra v10.13.4
and my boost version is 1.67.0
Any help is greatly appreciated

```
g++ -g -m64  -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK  -c  -I/usr/local/include -I../../include   -o build/stayClassification.o main.cpp

g++ -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -g -m64 -L/usr/local/lib -o build/stayClassification build/stayClassification.o  -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt -lCGAL -lpthread -lboost_log_setup-mt -lboost_log-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lgmp -lmpfr -lboost_iostreams-mt


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::put_integer<char>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::basic_ostringstreambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned int, unsigned int, char)", referenced from:





"boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert_impl(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned long, std::locale const&)", referenced from:

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please format your post such that essential information e.g. `<char>` is not lost. See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, your error messages mention stayClassification.o but it is not in the command arguments.

Comment: edited the post as per suggestion

Comment: You might be trying to link against boost built with libc++ (gcc uses libstdc++ by default). Try `-stdlib=libc++` compilation flag and/or clang++ instead of g++.